# node.js cannot find app.js after deployment to elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've just deployed my application to elastic beanstalk by doing an `eb push`.

My application isn't starting and the node.js logs say the following:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/var/app/current/dist/app.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3
```

There is definitely an app.js there as evidenced in my putty session

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-12-80 dist]$ pwd
/var/app/current/dist
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-12-80 dist]$ ls -l
total 20
-rw-r--r--  1 nodejs nodejs 3298 Apr 14 11:43 app.js
drwxr-xr-x 27 nodejs nodejs 4096 Apr 14 11:43 node_modules
-rw-r--r--  1 nodejs nodejs  858 Apr 14 11:43 package.json
drwxr-xr-x  3 nodejs nodejs 4096 Apr 14 11:43 public
drwxr-xr-x  2 nodejs nodejs 4096 Apr 14 11:43 routes
```

Anyone know what could be going wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: Could you show us the contents of your package.json?

Comment: does your package.json have a `"scripts": { "start": "node app.js"}` entry?

Comment: How you found the solution?